# Can't understand how parameters get fetched inside the wrapper function inside a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have this code:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.is_logged_in = False

def is_authenticated_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args[0].is_logged_in == True:
            function(args[0])
    return wrapper

@is_authenticated_decorator
def create_blog_post(user):
    print(f"This is {user.name}'s new blog post.")

new_user = User("angela")
new_user.is_logged_in = True
create_blog_post(new_user)
```

I don't understand how the parameter of the `create_blog_post(user)` gets fetched inside the inputs of the wrapper.

I understand that the

```py
@is_authenticated_decorator
def create_blog_post(user):
```

Is equivalent to

```py
create_blog_post = is_authenticated_decorator(create_blog_post)
```

I understand that `create_blog_post` becomes the wrapper

I understand that `create_blog_post(user)` calls `wrapper(user)`.

I just don't get how?!

Can someone explain the route/path that user parameters is taking to end up in the wrapper function?
thanks
your answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed:

The decoration comes down to `create_blog_post = is_authenticated_decorator(create_blog_post)`

That means we call that decorator which returns `wrapper`, but with a specific binding of its `function` parameter to our original `create_blog_post`. To make it easier, let's call the original `create_blog_post` as `original_create_blog_post`. So the `return` statement in `is_authenticated_decorator` returns this function:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0].is_logged_in == True:
        original_create_blog_post(args[0])
```

(`function` has been replaced with `orginal_create_blog_post` as that was the value we provided for the `function` parameter)

By assigning that returned value back to `create_blog_post` we have thus defined it as:

```
def create_blog_post(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0].is_logged_in == True:
        original_create_blog_post(args[0])
```

And if we expand the definition of what I call `original_create_blog_post`, we get:

```
def create_blog_post(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0].is_logged_in == True:
        print(f"This is {args[0].name}'s new blog post.")
```

Now when we call `create_blog_post(user)` the variable `args[0]` is `user`.